# How similar is US 8,943,201 to RFC 4033 (DNSSEC)?

Tags: us8943201

Patent [US8943201: Method for establishing encrypted channel](https://www.google.com/patents/US8943201) primarily deals with securely resolving domain names to set up communications. The whole concept of secure domain names is encapsulated in the DNSSEC RFC series. The claims of this patent read like [RFC 4033](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4033), but that RFC is from 2005 whereas this 2011 patent claims a priority date of 1998.

Am I wrong that these concepts are practically identical?